# why the window 'The program is still running! Do you want to kill it' during debugging

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

During debugging the python code, the window comes out after I input `rf.fit(aa,bb1)` and press 'enter' button. The python version I used is python2.7 and the system is UBUNTU12.10.

Here 'rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, verbose=2, compute_importances=True, n_jobs=-1)' is a function from sklearn. and variable 'aa, bb1' are shown in the picture. 'aa' is a DataFrame which is a data structure of Pandas library. 'bb1' is a list.

[image]

could you tell me what's wrong ? why does the warning window come out?

Comment: What does `rf.fit()` do?

Comment: rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, verbose=2, compute_importances=True, n_jobs=-1)
It is a scikit-learn function. rf is random forest

Comment: What was the last thing you did before typing in that line ?
Seems like you were running something and were trying to close a window or something.

Comment: @chrisfs previously, I ran the codes but it was very slow so I close it. Since I was debugging the code, I ran and it was very slow at that step and I close it for two or three times. Then each time, I try to run it, it shows that warning window. But for 'rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, verbose=2, compute_importances=True, n_jobs=-1)', if I removed 'n_jobs = -1', then everything will be fine. So what happened ?

Comment: Sounds like when you closed the window, you didn't actually stop the program that was running. Beyond that I don't know.

Comment: @chrisfs  I once restarted my PC. However the window still comes out.

Comment: This can happen when you hit a quit() statement inside your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message is "Your program is still running!\n Do you want to kill it?" and comes from `lib\pythonX.X\idlelib\PyShell.py`.

Because you run the program in an `Python IDEL Shell` Env and your script is now running but you want to close the window.

`IDEL` is another name of Python GUI Shell.